# Dispatched click event: Prevent browser to jump to clicked element

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a quite complex product in WooCommerce with a complicated variation selector.

To simplify things you can just click on a photo of a variation you like (anywhere on the page) and have it selected for you.

So I just added an eventlistener on the photos that triggers a click on the correct variation checkbox, as soon as you click the image:

```
Photo_Variation1.addEventListener('click', () => {
    Variation1.click()
})
```

This works fine, but then the browser automatically jumps to the original variation selector – because it gets focused after/during the click-event. This is rather confusing UX-wise.

So I tried for hours to find a solution. But so far my only lousy success was making it work in Safari, by adding this to the eventListener:

```
Variation1.blur()
```

I found out it doesn't work in other browsers, because there the focus event happens directly after the mousedown-event. (In Safari it's after the click.)

However, when I tried to solely trigger the `mousedown` function (with a `"preventDefault"`) nothing gets selected, at all.

Do you have an idea how I can trigger a click and prevent focusing the clicked element or any another workaround that stops the browser from jumping around?

PS:
I am using JavaScript for just 8 hours, so have mercy, please. :D

Comment: Try "prevent default" on the click events

Comment: I tried this with no effect:
Variation1.click(function (e) {e.preventDefault;});

Should I have done it differently?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically set a checkbox as checked by doing the following:

```
Photo_Variation1.addEventListener('click', () => {
     var myCheckBox = document.getElementById("myCheckBoxId");

    if(myCheckBox.checked) {
        myCheckBox.checked = false;
    } else {
        myCheckBox.checked = true;
    }
})
```

Here is more info to help you as well.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint!
This changes the form, but doesn't refresh it. So price changes are not visible and adding the product to the cart doesn't work either.
Do you have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Ah.. just found out. For further reference: You need to dispatch an event and make sure it bubbles. I used:

document.getElementById("pa_size").dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));